# ASANA API - get only projects associated to me

Tags: asana, asana-connect

when you query `/projects` I get every project in the organization(a-lot) ... is there anyway to just get projects that I am interested in (ie task assigned to me, mention of me, or one that I have flaged as following?)

I have also tried

```
users/me/projects
projects?followers=me
```

Comment: I believe my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168833/slow-responses-using-the-asana-api) would answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

That's a really interesting idea. We don't currently have a way of doing that - even in the product! - in part because everyone's definition of "interesting to me" is a little different. For instance, there's no global way to look up, for a user, all the comments they're mentioned in - mentioning adds a user as a follower to the task, sure, but they might be removed from the followers list subsequently. Should projects with tasks that I hearted be included? What about projects with tasks that have comments that I hearted? Projects with tasks that I'm following, sure - but what if the last time I followed a task in that project was over a year ago, and the task I followed is long since complete? Since tasks can be in multiple projects, does it make sense to include a project that I may have never even seen, but includes a task that's also in a project I work on, and so I've touched it? It's a tricky question to get right for everyone, to be sure.

In the meantime, you can get tasks that are assigned to you in a workspace (`GET /tasks?workspace=[id]&assignee=me`) and then crawl all the tasks to find the projects they're in (I know, not terribly elegant).

We currently don't expose projects/tasks you're following or projects you've favorited (starred) via the API. And as far as I know there's no way to query stories/tasks you're mentioned in via the API *or* the app.

Comment: ok :) yeah currently I am just listing all projects by team basically ... but its slow and not very pretty. (I am working on something like havest but more what I want from a time tracking app) It would be nice to be able to say `has_task_with_asignee=me`  (thats really what I would like.. since I have the ear of someone who might be able to do something about it :P )

Comment: Heh, it sounds a little... specialized. We'd be unlikely to support *just* that particular parameter, but maybe at some point we *might* build something like Facebook did with FQL? It's not incredibly high on the priority list though, I don't think.